# Android SDK Setup Problems

Tags: android

Im new to android and am just trying to install the SDK. I have everything else done. When i run the SDK Setup.exe (ive added the ./tools to the path already.) It gives me the famous cannot fetch URL error.

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: Permission denied: connect

I tried the force http option and also manually adding a http:// version of the above url. It does not work at all. I am working on a windows 7 64 bit pc. Any help would be appreciated.
Ramesh

Comment: Hey sorry let me know what i should use and i will change it. Newbie mistake

Comment: Not really a programming question, but no need to downvote it for that...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your firewall is blocking tcp/udp connection from Java.exe process?

Answer (score 0):

Try running from the command prompt.

tools\android.bat update sdk
it launches the sdk which works.
Thanks,
Ramesh